# union unusual behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to union two tables with the same field into one master table but for some reason im getting a weird result.

```
select count(*)
from staging.sandoval_parcels
where parcel_id = 0;
```

returns 0

```
select count(*)
from staging.bernalillo_parcels
where parcel_id = 0;
```

returns 0

but when i merge the tables using

```
CREATE TABLE staging.master_parcels
AS
    SELECT * FROM bernalillo_parcels
        UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM sandoval_parcels
;
```

then

```
select count(*)
from staging.master_parcels
where parcel_id = 0;
```

returns 85553

both tables have the same fields and the fields are the same data type,also, no of the values for any field are missing, thus no nulls, why am i getting ids = 0 when either of the table have parcel_ids = 0?

Comment: is `staging` in the search_path? (your table `CREATE TABLE master_parcels` is created without an explicit schema-prefix) Try: `select count(*)
from master_parcels
where parcel_id = 0;` instead

Comment: yes it is, i forgot to include it but it is. The table gets created in a python script and i use the `cursor.execute("SET search_path TO staging,public;")`
to specify the order

Comment: Since you don't explicitly give metadata in your `create` statement, could it be defaulting to 0?  Are any of the values `null` in the source tables?

Comment: ill have to check that @stephen

Comment: would more info help identify whats going on?

Comment: Yes: the **actual** commands to reproduce the problem. (I just tried, and it worked as expected)

Comment: looks like null converted to 0 to me.

Comment: You said the fields are the same, but are they on the same order?

Comment: no same order @JuanCarlosOropeza does the order matter?

Comment: Yes, order matter ;)

Comment: Oh, well that might explain the whole thing @JuanCarlosOropeza. let me try it and ill accept the answer if that's the case

Comment: count(*) is different from *.... so if you UNION ALL them together naturally it will get all data and looking at the OP you don't have a where clause

Comment: @maSTAShuFu the `UNION ALL` is used to create a new table. Then the count is on that new table.

Comment: my point is the create table union all does even have a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the fields matter, replace the `*` for the explicit name, other wise the second query field will be inserted on the first query position. But not necessarily on the same field you want.

```
CREATE TABLE staging.master_parcels
AS
    SELECT parcel_id, field1 ... FROM bernalillo_parcels
        UNION ALL
    SELECT parcel_id, field1 ... FROM sandoval_parcels
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Union will merge tables even if the column order is not the same.  If all of the columns match and are in the same order, it will union distinct values and not create duplicates if the rows are the same for each table. Having the order and data type be the same is important.